# use $.get method to assign data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below function that loops through each link and assigns a default data-content attribute.

```
getContent: function () {
    $('ul#links a').each(function () {
        var t = $(this),
            content = 'this is a default content';
        t.attr('data - content', content.tolowercase());
    })
}
```

I want to replace the default content with the contents from the HTML link using the get method. How do I go about this one.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass `getContent` as a callback method to `$.get` which fetches the data.

```
getContent: function (data){
  $(‘ul#links a’).each (function(){
    const t = $(this)
    const content = '//Loop the data variable to generate this content'
    t.attr(‘data-content’, content.tolowercase());
  })
}

function fetchData () {
  return $.get(<URL>, getContent)
}

fetchData()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using getcontent as callback?

Comment: You can do it using promises but that'll still involve a callback.